# How can I get fluid typography that gradually change type scale using the max() CSS Function?

Tags: html, css, font-size, typography, viewport-units

I’m a big fan of fluid typography and I want a website I’m developing to adopt it. Recently, I learned about the `max()` CSS Function. I thought of using it to get fluid typography. In particular, I want the text on webpages to start from a specific type scale and then to adopt a different one. To be concrete, I want the text to use the Minor Third scale on a small starting viewport. When the viewport becomes larger, I want the text to use the Perfect Fifth scale instead. I want to get a result like the one [Utopia](https://utopia.fyi/) lets you obtain. There, you specify the two type scales you want to use on different viewports. I want to try to replicate the same effect, but using only the `max()` Function, since I don’t want to provide a “max viewport”: my text must scale infinitely. So far, I’ve tried using this code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <style>
          h1   { font-size: max(2.488rem, 11.089vw); }
          h2   { font-size: max(2.074rem, 6.854vw); }    
          h3   { font-size: max(1.728rem, 4.236vw); }
          h4   { font-size: max(1.44rem, 2.618vw); }
          h5   { font-size: max(1.2rem, 1.618vw); }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Heading 1</h1>
       <h2>Heading 2</h2>
       <h3>Heading 3</h3>
       <h4>Heading 4</h4>
       <h5>Heading 5</h5>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What this code does is using the `max()` Function for every heading, whose first member is the scale defined by the Minor Third scale, while the second one is the scale defined by the Perfect Fifth scale. To see what I’m taking about, try resizing the viewport after running the code snippet above and you’ll see the heading changing scales. I don’t know if this code does exactly what I’m trying to achieve (that is, to switch from a scale to another one), but it seems to. What I want to avoid, however, is the interval that occurs from, for example, the `h1` and the `h2` elements while they change when resizing the viewport. Specifically, the `h1` starts adopting the new scale **before** the `h2` does. This makes sense since the two maximum values calculated are different, but I’d like all my headings to start adopting the new scale at the same time, that is when I resize the viewport.

Comment: Take a look here https://css-tricks.com/simplified-fluid-typography/

Comment: I already read it, but it doesn’t answer to my question.

Comment: Why not use media queries for this? You don't have to put a cap on the largest size.

Comment: @disinfor how would you apply them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found the best solution was to use something like:

```
:root {
 --step6:calc(1.602rem + 5.063vw);
 --step5:calc(1.424rem + 3.375vw);
 --step4:calc(1.266rem + 2.25vw);
 --step3:calc(1.125rem + 1.5vw);
 --step2:calc(1rem + 1vw);
 --step1:calc(0.889rem + 0.667vw);
 --step0:calc(0.79rem + 0.444vw)
}
```

I use these CSS variables to specify the sizes of elements and let the text scale indefinitely, without the need to use media queries to specify precise points in which my design should change. I get the effect I was looking for with just the use of these variables. For example, an `h1` element can use:

```
h1 { font-size:var(--step6) }
```

and an `h2` element:

```
h2 { font-size: var(--step5) }
```

This lets me say: *«I provide only the smallest values. When the viewport grows up, I want the sizes to scale indefinitely, using this ratio»*. Of couse, I use these variables not ony with font sizes, but also with other properties such as margins, paddings, etc.

Comment: Since you answered your own question, provide more context to show how you actually used this code with your markup. That would make this answer more valuable to future visitors.

Comment: I still don't see how this addresses your original question: _...but I’d like all my headings to start adopting the new scale at the same time, that is when I resize the viewport._ The CSS variables and scale (Minor Third and Major Fifth) don't change as you resize the viewport. The scale stays the same.

Comment: It’s not correct, since the steps are defined using the Minor Third and Major Fifth ratio, as well as using different `vw` units.

Comment: To be clear in your answer, all of your variables (`calc` values) will change from Minor Third to Major Fifth at the same time as you change the viewport width? E.g. step 1 through 6 will all change to a new scale at the same time at the same viewport width.

Comment: Yes, and that’s what I wanted to achieve!

Comment: Cool! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might do it using media queries:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: max(2.488rem, 11.089vw);
}

h2 {
  font-size: max(2.074rem, 6.854vw);
}

h3 {
  font-size: max(1.728rem, 4.236vw);
}

h4 {
  font-size: max(1.44rem, 2.618vw);
}

h5 {
  font-size: max(1.2rem, 1.618vw);
}


/* tablet */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: max(3.488rem, 16.089vw);
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: max(3.074rem, 11.854vw);
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: max(2.728rem, 9.236vw);
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: max(2.44rem, 7.618vw);
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: max(2.2rem, 5.618vw);
  }
}


/* large screens and up */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: max(4.488rem, 30.089vw);
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: max(4.074rem, 18.854vw);
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: max(3.728rem, 16.236vw);
  }
  h4 {
    font-size: max(3.44rem, 14.618vw);
  }
  h5 {
    font-size: max(3.2rem, 10.618vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <h2>Heading 2</h2>
  <h3>Heading 3</h3>
  <h4>Heading 4</h4>
  <h5>Heading 5</h5>
</body>

</html>
```

I made up numbers for the font size increase and you could add more browser viewport break sizes and even use `rem` values instead of `px`.

Comment: I try to avoid media queries.

Comment: You specifically asked how to apply with media queries. Why do you avoid them?

Comment: Yes, I asked how someone would apply them, but then I understood I want to avoid them. I appreciate your answer, but I opted for something else, since I found it was the best way to solve my problem.

Comment: That’s totally fine you found another way! I’m wondering why you wanted to avoid them.

Comment: I improved my answer.